# Python - can't decipher serial port bits

Tags: python, serial-port, string-formatting, type-conversion

I have a MaxiMet GMX600 weather station.

Here is the manual:
http://gillinstruments.com/data/manuals/maximet-manual-iss1.pdf

I have it connect to my serial port and it's spitting out data every 1 second. Which is great!

Unfortunately, I can't decipher the data...

I *should* be seeing strings like this:

```
$WIMWV ,069,R,004.06,N,A*00
$WIMWV,122,T,,N,A*14
$WIXDR,C,+023.2,C,TEMP,P,1.0281,B,PRESS,H,037,P,RH,Y,000.0,M,PRECIP*0A

Followed 1 second later by:

$WIMWV ,238,R,000.46,N,A*06
$WIMWV,303,T,,N,A*15
$WIXDR,C,+023.2,C,TEMP,P,1.0281,B,PRESS,H,037,P,RH,Y,000.0,M,PRECIP*0A

Followed 1 second later by:

$WIMWV ,130,R,000.21,N,A*0C
$WIMWV,205,T,,N,A*12
$WIXDR,C,+023.2,C,TEMP,P,1.0281,B,PRESS,H,038,P,RH,Y,000.0,M,PRECIP*05
```

Unfortunately, all I'm seeing is gobbledy-gook such as:

```
�����������������W���������������������������������������������������������������]���}���������������������u���+��+����; ���; �����; k��K; ���K;k��;� ����;���;� ���;���u������������

Followed one second later by:

�叙���������������������W�����������������������������������������������������������������]��哙���������������������W���������������������������������������������������������������]��坙

Followed one second later by:

�����]���y����������������������W�����������������������������������������������������������������]��叙���������������������W�����������������������������������������������������������������]�
```

Here's my Python code:

```
import time
import serial
import binascii
import struct

ser=serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
        baudrate=19200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=5
)
while 1:
        y=0
        str=""
        while y<200:
                #x=binascii.b2a_qp(ser.read()).strip().strip("=")
                #x=binascii.hexlify(ser.read()).strip()
                x=ser.read().strip()
                #x=struct.pack('<h',int(ser.read()))

                str=x+str
                y=y+1
                #ser.flush()

        print str
```

You can see I've been trying to manipulate the bytes, but nothing is happening. I keep getting gobbldy-gook.

If I uncomment the line `bin2ascii.hexlify(ser.read()).strip()`, I get output like:

```
9fa78d919fa75dfb00ebe59599f9a79f9f9f9fa78fa3979fa9a795a38d998b9f958b9f9d57999fa59b9da5959d9f9ba79fa39f9f9fa79fa39f9f9f9f9fa79ba38d9f9fa9a79da39f9b9fa9a78d979fa799a39d9d9f9da78d9b9fa79d9fa39f9f9fa7998f9fa75dfb00ebe57d99f9a79f9f9f9fa78fa3979fa9a795a38f998b9f958b9f9d57999fa59b9da5959d9f9ba79fa39f9f9fa79fa39f9f9f9f9fa79ba38d9f9fa9a79da39f9b9fa9a78d979fa799a39d9d9f9da79b999fa79f9fa39f9f9fa7938f9fa75dfb

Followed one second later by:

9f9fa79d9fa39f9f9fa78d959fa75dfb00ebe57999f9a79f9f9f9fa78fa3979fa9a795a39d978b9f958b9f9d57999fa59b9da5959d9f9ba79fa39f9f9fa79fa39f9f9f9f9fa79ba38d9f9fa9a79da39f9b9fa9a78d979fa799a39d9d9f9da79d9599a79d9fa39f9f9fa795979fa75dfb00ebe59b99f9a79f9f9f9fa78fa3979fa9a795a39f978b9f958b9f9d57999fa59b9da5959d9f9ba79fa39f9f9fa79fa39f9f9f9f9fa79ba38d9f9fa9a79da39f9b9fa9a78d979fa799a39d9d9f9da7959b9fa79d9fa39f9f

Followed one second later by:

99a39d9d9f9da79b9d9fa79d9fa39f9f9fa793939fa75dfb00ebe57b99f9a79f9f9f9fa78fa3979fa9a795a399978b9f958b9f9d57999fa59b9da5959d9f9ba79fa39f9f9fa79fa39f9f9f9f9fa79ba38d9f9fa9a79da39f9b9fa9a78d979fa799a39d9d9f9da79f9d9fa79d9fa39f9f9fa797939fa75dfb00ebe59f99f9a79f9f9f9fa78fa3979fa9a795a39b978b9f958b9f9d57999fa59b9da5959d9f9ba79fa39f9f9fa79fa39f9f9f9f9fa79ba38d9f9fa9a79da39f9b9fa9a78d979fa799a39d9d9f9da795
```

ASCII only goes up to `0x7F`, so I guess all these `0x9_` numbers are producing the funny characters?

I'm afraid I'm really stuck. I can't decipher it - my Python skills aren't good enough and I've been at this for hours... Does anyone have any Python suggestions as to how I can fix this output?

Comment: A bad signal ground can garble the data.  The pin-out on this device seems non-standard; do you have a special cable designed for this instrument?

Comment: This is very useful information. There are some shielding grounds which I tied together and put on the GND pin of a Raspberry Pi. I guess this is a bad idea... In the morning, I will attach it to the manufacturer's USB cable and a Windows computer... I thought I wouldn't have to go near Windows...